# Handling and optimizing a range slider in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

If you run the script below, You get a data table representing iris data and a range slider which gives you values greater than and equal to the chosen point on the prior circle of your selection in the slider. I want a logic such that when left slider node is kept at say 5 and right slider at 7, I want the data to be displayed "= and above 5" and "< and equal to 7".These values however should be dynamic. Also for the two circles on the sliders, is there a way to give triangle widgets which are small in size. Attaching the snapshot for reference. Thanks and please help.

```
#App
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(DT)

#Declaring the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Slider Test"),
fluidRow(
column(4,
         sliderInput("range", "Select the Name Similarity %",
                     min = 4, max = 8,
                     value = c(min,max) ))

),

# Create a new row for the table.
fluidRow(
DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)
)
#Declaring the Server
server <- function(input, output) {
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
Prod_total1      <-  subset(iris, as.numeric(sub("%", "", 
iris$Sepal.Length)) >= input$range)
  Prod_total1
}))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Slider Snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to access `sliderInput` values in the range mode please use `input$range[1]` to access the first extreme and `input$range[2]` to access the second

```
#App
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(DT)

#Declaring the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Slider Test"),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           sliderInput("range", "Select the Name Similarity %",
                       min = 4, max = 8,
                       value = c(min,max) ))

  ),

  # Create a new row for the table.
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)




#Declaring the Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    iris[iris$Sepal.Length >= input$range[1] & iris$Sepal.Length <= input$range[2],]
  }))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: When I keep the first point of slider at 5, I still see sepal.length values less than 5, I want value >= first point and value<= second point on the slider. Please help

Comment: Exactly, but when i run your code, I still see Sepal.Length values less than 5, when the left slider is placed at 5, kindly check

Comment: Any clues here?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is awesome, great help.

Comment: Also, is there any way to change the shape of the round circles on the slider to little triangles?

Comment: please help me with this post here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683969/sankey-diagram-using-plotly?noredirect=1#comment80315660_46683969